# Does Basemap allow to print the number of datapoints plotted?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have flight locations from several areas around the world and when I choose a specific area to plot the points, I want to know how many points are being plotted.

Is there a functionality to output the number of points that show up on my map?

Comment: You may simply get this information from the underlying data.

Comment: I ended up writing a function to grab the number of points in the lat/long bounds. The issue was that I have many data points that are not plotted on the map since I am restricting the map area to a certain lat/lon compared to my entire dataset. When I posted this question, I was wondering if there was a parameter that allowed for the print of output of n points plotted on the map.